# How to serialize-deserialize any of 3 object types, one of which contains an abstract class?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I am sending 3 .net objects over the network:

```
 - List<int>
 - List<ParentObject>
 - string
```

This is how I'm serializing (same for all types):

```
JsonSerializerSettings JSsettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Arrays
        };

        string message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listOfParents, JSsettings);
        //listOfParents is  of type List<ParentObject>
```

The ParentObject is an abstract class and has two child classes. It has a property to get which child type it represents.

```
public enum EntityType {Child1, Child2};

class ParentObject
{
  public EntityType et { get; set; }
  //..other members
}
```

I want to call 3 different functions based on which of the 3 objects is received.

```
Object genericObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(message, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
            });

        if (genericObject is List<int>)
        {
          List<int> myList= (List<int>)genericObject;
          myfunction1(myList);
        }
        if (genericObject is List<ParentObject>)
        {
         //etc..
```

The ParentObject is causing problems at DeserializeObject() because it says "Could not create an instance of type ParentObject. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated". So I was thinking I might need to use CustomCreationConverter at http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/CustomCreationConverter.htm

That still wouldn't solve my problem since the CustomCreationConverter needs the type **during** deserialization whereas I don't check the type until **after** deserialization.

Any suggestions to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If I use objects defined like this:

```
public enum EntityType { Child1, Child2 };

abstract class ParentObject
{
    public EntityType et { get; set; }
}

class ChildClass : ParentObject
{
    public int ChildClassProp { get; set; }

    public ChildClass()
    {
        this.et = EntityType.Child1;
    }
}

class ChildClass2 : ParentObject
{
    public int ChildClass2Prop { get; set; }

    public ChildClass2()
    {
        this.et = EntityType.Child2;
    }
}
```

Then I can happily deserialize derived classes(`ChildClass` and `ChildClass2`) to `ParentObject` like this:

```
JsonSerializerSettings JSsettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
};

List<ParentObject> list = new List<ParentObject>();
list.Add(new ChildClass() { ChildClassProp = 1 });
list.Add(new ChildClass2() { ChildClass2Prop = 2 });

string message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list,
      Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, JSsettings);

list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ParentObject>>(message, JSsettings);
```

Where `message` looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "$type": "ConsoleApplication4.ChildClass, ConsoleApplication4",
    "ChildClassProp": 1,
    "et": 0
  },
  {
    "$type": "ConsoleApplication4.ChildClass2, ConsoleApplication4",
    "ChildClass2Prop": 2,
    "et": 1
  }
]
```

The key in this one was using `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto` for both serialization and deserialization. Using `TypeNameHandling.Arrays` creates a message that looks like this:

```
{
  "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[ConsoleApplication4.ParentObject, ConsoleApplication4]], mscorlib",
  "$values": [
    {
      "ChildClassProp": 1,
      "et": 0
    },
    {
      "ChildClass2Prop": 2,
      "et": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that the types of the list items are not included, only the type of the list, hence the error you were getting.

**Edit:**

I think the easiest way to get this working the way you want is to define a simple class like this one that acts as a thin wrapper around the object you are serializing:

```
class ObjectContainer
{
    public object Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then the code would look like this (note the change to `TypeNameHandling.Auto`):

```
JsonSerializerSettings JSsettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
};

List<ParentObject> list = new List<ParentObject>();
list.Add(new ChildClass() { ChildClassProp = 1 });
list.Add(new ChildClass2() { ChildClass2Prop = 2 });

ObjectContainer container = new ObjectContainer()
{
    Data = list
};

string message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(container,
      Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, JSsettings);

var objectContainer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectContainer>(message, JSsettings);

if (objectContainer.Data is List<int>)
{
    Console.Write("objectContainer.Data is List<int>");
}
else if (objectContainer.Data is List<ParentObject>)
{
    Console.Write("objectContainer.Data is List<ParentObject>");
}
else if (objectContainer.Data is string)
{
    Console.Write("objectContainer.Data is string");
}
```

The reason I have gone for this approach is that Json.Net will take care of almost all the work. Simply calling the non-generic `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` method is fine, but you would then need to do additional work as this method returns a `JContainer`, not an `object`.

Comment: I can't use the line `list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ParentObject>>(message, JSsettings);` because I don't know which of the 3 object types I'll receive. I have to deserialize without knowing the type, then check the type in if..else, cast it to the type and call the corresponding function.